# Получение id для записи в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Такой вопрос:
Добавляю новую строку в форму, которая может принимать значение "H" или "N". В базу данных должна записываться как слияние буквы и id заказа, например H50 и N66.
Выглядит так

```
Название: ...
Описание: ...
Код: ...
Новый префикс: H
```

А в базе данных

```
id 80
name ...
desc ...
code ...
new_pref H80
```

Так вот, как мне получить id записи, которая ещё не сформирована?

Comment: Да, забыл сказать, id задаётся автоматически, пользователь его не указывает.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас в таблице используется движок InnoDB, можно воспользоваться механизмом транзакций: начать транзакцию, вставить новую запись, получить LAST_INSERT_ID(), обновить запись и сделать коммит транзакции (все можно сделать в рамках одного обращения к MySQL):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO insert_test 
  SET name = 'Имя', desc = 'Описание';
UPDATE insert_test
  SET new_pref = CONCAT('N', id)
  WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Минусующим: если минусуете ответ, пишите комментарий, почему.

Answer (score 1):

> как мне получить id записи, которая ещё не сформирована?

Никак.

> В базу данных должно записываться как слияние буквы и id заказа,

Не должно.

Данные в базе не должны дублироваться. "Слияние" надо получать при выборке.

Answer (score -1):

### Способ 1

1. Извлечь максимальное значение `ID` из таблицы - считаем, что это действительно актуальное значение `ID` (тут наверно стоит подумать про блокировки таблицы от записи в параллельном процессе);
2. Если `ID == 0`, то это первая запись;
3. Увеличиваем `ID` на 1 и формируем нужные поля;
4. Записываем все в БД, снимаем блокировки.

### Способ 2

1. Ни о чем не волнуемся - просто вставляем запись в БД с `new_pref=N/M/H`;
2. При помощи ф-ии `mysql_insert_id` (или ее эквивалента в PDO-mysql) получаем последний автоинкрементный ID;
3. Делаем запрос `$sql = "update TABLE set new_pref='N/M/H".$ID." where id=".$ID`

Comment: Минусующим: если минусуете ответ, пишите комментарий, почему.